# Elasticsearch authentication error with shield

Tags: elasticsearch, installshield, elasticsearch-shield

It's very stange to see this scenario,

**Environment Elasticsearch 2.0 and kibana 4.2 Shield version 2.0**

I have created the users and roles but If I run the elasticsearch I can see the following

```
warning 
[2015-12-12 02:39:08,936][INFO ][node                     ] [Asbestos Man] starting ...
[2015-12-12 02:39:10,288][WARN ][shield.authc.esusers     ] [Asbestos Man] no users found in users file [/home/ec2-user/elasticsearch-2.0.0/config/shield/users]. use bin/shield/esusers to add users and role mappings
[2015-12-12 02:39:10,298][WARN ][shield.authc.esusers     ] [Asbestos Man] no entries found in users_roles file [/home/ubuntu-user

[ubuntu-user@ec2-22-09-21-322 elasticsearch-2.0.0]$

Here is my userlist which I had created,
bin/shield/esusers list
demo           : kibana4
webshop        : kibana4
user1          : tab014
kibana         : kibana4
```

I'm seeing Elasticsearch authentication exception in kibana url?

[image]

Comment: This looks like Shield is using one config file to read users details while you created the users somewhere else.

Comment: `bin/shield/esusers list` what's the location for this?

Comment: This is the path                                                                                   /home/ec2-user/elasticsearch-2.0.0/bin/shield/esusers list

Comment: And do you have another installation here? `/home/ec2-user/elasticsearch-2.0.0/config/shield/users`

Comment: What I'm trying to establish: do you have **two Elasticsearch installations**? `/home/ec2-user/elasticsearch-2.0.0/` **AND** `/home/ubuntu-user....` The logs show two different paths.

Comment: That's my typo mistake. I will edit it. I have two installations of different versions.

Comment: Ok. Can you start ES again and provide here or in a gist the complete startup logs? (without modifications of any sort)

Comment: @AndreiStefan Attached Screenshot for the same

Comment: According to the logs (i.e. the screenshot you posted), you're starting the ES 2.1.0 version so whatever users you have configured in ES 2.0.0 (i.e. what you showed above in your question) will not be there, it's pretty normal.

Comment: @Val I have changed my screenshot

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to see the full log, i.e. at least as much as the previous one?

Comment: In my opinion, this is only because you've created your users when logged in as `ubuntu-user` but you're starting the service as `ec2-user`. Can that be?

Comment: No actually. I just edited the user name for security reasons. There is no user like Ubuntu in my server @ val